# Unicenter Software Delivery 4 not able to connect to MS SQL 2000 Database after W2003 SP2 upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2003, database, deployment

Yesterday I installed the Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2 on a Windows Server 2003 which has Unicenter Software Delivery 4 installed.
Prior to the installation I disabled every CA service on the server (Brightstor, SDO , RCO, TNG) and the MS SQL 2000 service.

After the installation of the SP2 I enabled the services again but the Unicenter Service is not able to connect to the MS SQL 2000 Database anymore. The database itself is up and running and I can connect to it with the Enterprise Manager.

A *dbcc checkdb* doesnt return any errors on the Unicenter database.

The Unicenter service throws the following error messages during startup:

```
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,272 Installation Manager in init phase
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,694 Process IM(L) - [004152] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,694 sqls error details:
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,694 (null)
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 ##EXCEPTION## TableError T@:PS_SQLS\isam_db.cxx:744.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 ##EXCEPTION## TableError C@:TaskmgrL\ASMTML.CXX:596.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 ##EXCEPTION## ErrorCode: 4711 in SDDATA:Isam::Isam. Process IM(L) - [004152] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 sqls error details:
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 (null)
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069  returned 0.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,084 Persistent Storage could not be opened.
Error cause is found in the ASM Event Log. Restart Task Manager.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,084 Failed to open database.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,084 Installation Manager ends>
```

If I check the Unicenter configutation with *chkmib_l* the tool throws an exception and creates a small dump file.

```
An Exception Occurred:

Time:
27/05 09:49:38,928

Reason:
ChkMIB_l.exe caused an UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION in module kernel32.dll at 7C82001B:77E4BEE7

Registers:
EAX=0012F908  EBX=00000000  ECX=00000000  EDX=02410004  ESI=0012F998 
EDI=0012F998  EBP=0012F958  ESP=0012F904  EIP=77E4BEE7  FLG=00000206 
CS =7C82001B      DS =B90023      SS =120023 
ES =120023      FS =7C82003B      GS =3F0000

Call Stack:
7C82001B:77E4BEE7 (0xE06D7363 0x00000001 0x00000003 0x0012F98C) kernel32.dll
7C82001B:77BB3259 (0x0012F9B8 0x2B017C50 0x2B024404 0x00B68C98) MSVCRT.dll
7C82001B:2B010C42 (0x00020003 0x010C00FE 0x003F0190 0x00B69050) PS.dll


<< SOFTWARE DELIVERY INSTANCE INFO >>

TRIGGER       0(1) instances:
JCE           0(1) instances:
TM            0(1) instances:
IM            0(1) instances:
DM            0(1) instances:
DPU           0(71) instances:
NATF          0(1) instances:
MIBCONV       0(0) instances:
API           0(4) instances:
DTSFT         0(0) instances:
TNGPOP        0(0) instances:
DGATE         0(0) instances:

<< FLUSHING MEMORY TRACES >>


<< STOP FLUSHING MEMORY TRACES >>
```

I compared the configuration of the SDO service and the system configuration with another server on which the Windows Server 2003 SP2 is installed and SDO is working.

The configuration is the same and the same driver and software versions are used.

Do you have any idea what causes the connection issue? Should I deinstall the unicenter service and make a fresh installation on the server or should I remove the Windows Server 2003 SP2?

I don't want to remove the SP2 because it's a requirement for WSUS3 SP2 and I really don't want to know how many possible exploits are possible in such an old system ;-)

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

---

Below you can find more detailed information about the system and the SDO service.

**psinfo output (system information)**

```
System information for \\CZZAAS1003:
Uptime:                    0 days 14 hours 38 minutes 50 seconds
Kernel version:            Microsoft Windows Server 2003, Multiprocessor Free
Product type:              Standard Edition
Product version:           5.2
Service pack:              2
Kernel build number:       3790
Install date:              23.9.2004, 11:16:11s
IE version:                6.0000
System root:               C:\WINDOWS
Processors:                2
Processor speed:           2.3 GHz
Processor type:            Intel(R) Xeon(TM) CPU
Physical memory:           1024 MB
Video driver:              RAGE XL PCI Family (Microsoft Corporation)
```

**sdver output (Unicenter Software delivery version)**

```
Unicenter Software Delivery 4.0 SP1 I2 ENU [2901]
Copyright 2004 Computer Associates International, Incorporated
```

**ms sql 2000 version and odbc driver version**

```
MS SQL 2000 Server Standard Edition
Product Version: 8.00.760 (SP3)

ODBC Driver: SQL Server - Version 2000.86.3959.00
```

**complete Unicenter Software delivery service log file**

```
TRIGGER[1] 27/05 10:38:28,366 SD Trigger Agent has started
NATF[1] 27/05 10:38:28,928 Initiation phase finished
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,272 Installation Manager in init phase
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,694 Process IM(L) - [004152] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,694 sqls error details:
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:31,694 (null)
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 ##EXCEPTION## TableError T@:PS_SQLS\isam_db.cxx:744.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 ##EXCEPTION## TableError C@:TaskmgrL\ASMTML.CXX:596.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 ##EXCEPTION## ErrorCode: 4711 in SDDATA:Isam::Isam. Process IM(L) - [004152] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 sqls error details:
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069 (null)
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,069  returned 0.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,084 Persistent Storage could not be opened.
Error cause is found in the ASM Event Log. Restart Task Manager.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,084 Failed to open database.
IM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,084 Installation Manager ends
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,116 Task Manager in init phase
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,334 Process TM(L) - [006132] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,334 sqls error details:
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,334 (null)
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 ##EXCEPTION## TableError T@:PS_SQLS\isam_db.cxx:744.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 ##EXCEPTION## TableError C@:TaskmgrL\ASMTML.CXX:596.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 ##EXCEPTION## ErrorCode: 4711 in SDDATA:Isam::Isam. Process TM(L) - [006132] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 sqls error details:
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 (null)
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381  returned 0.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 Persistent Storage could not be opened.
Error cause is found in the ASM Event Log. Restart Task Manager.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 Failed to open database.
TM[1] 27/05 10:38:32,381 Task Manager ends
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:33,272 Dialogue Manager is now active
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,397 API Server Process in init phase
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,397 API - SDNLS_Init
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,397 API - connectEM
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,412 API - apiServ.init
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:34,678  **AND** 1 Agents triggered
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,709 Process API(L) - [005680] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,709 sqls error details:
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,709 (null)
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 ##EXCEPTION## TableError T@:PS_SQLS\isam_db.cxx:744.
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 ##EXCEPTION## TableError C@:MainAPIL\APISERVL.CXX:246.
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 ##EXCEPTION## ErrorCode: 4711 in SDDATA:Isam::Isam. Process API(L) - [005680] failed to open database SDDATA. dbopen() call failed.
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 sqls error details:
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 (null)
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756  returned 0.
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 Open of the database failed.
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 API - apiServ.init complete
API[1] 27/05 10:38:34,756 API - start_APIServer
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:34,803 CZZAAR1037
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:35,772 DPU in init phase
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,100 >> GetManagerData
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,287 >> SetCompInfo
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,334 >> GetContainerList
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,350 getJobState 3 from 5b6ad
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,350 getJobState 3 from 5b6ad
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,350 getJobState 3 from 5b6b7
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,350 getJobState 3 from 5b6b7
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,350 getJobState 3 from 5b6c1
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,350 getJobState 3 from 5b6c1
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b6cb
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b6cb
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b6f9
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b6f9
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b71a
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b71a
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,366 getJobState 3 from 5b724
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,381 getJobState 3 from 5b724
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b72e
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b72e
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b738
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b738
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b742
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b742
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b74c
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b74c
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b756
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b756
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b78a
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b78a
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b7af
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,397 getJobState 3 from 5b7af
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,522 >> SetCompAttr
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,569 >> SetDetected
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 disconnect
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b6ad
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b6b7
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b6c1
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b6cb
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b6f9
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b71a
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b724
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b72e
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b738
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b742
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b74c
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b756
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b78a
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 getJobState 3 from 5b7af
DPU[1:CZZAAR1037] 27/05 10:38:36,584 DPU ends
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:38,006  **AND** 0 Agents triggered
JCE[1] 27/05 10:38:38,053 JCE starts
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:38,287 CZZAAS1003
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:38,412 DPU in init phase
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:38,647 >> GetManagerData
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:38,756 >> SetCompInfo
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:38,787 >> GetContainerList
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:38,850  **AND** 1 Agents triggered
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:38,928 CZZAAR1124
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,053 DPU in init phase
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,272 >> GetManagerData
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:39,334  **AND** 1 Agents triggered
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,381 >> SetCompInfo
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,412 >> GetContainerList
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:39,412 CZZAAR1125
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,428 getJobState 3 from 5b88e
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,428 getJobState 3 from 5b88e
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:39,491 >> SetCompAttr
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,522 >> SetCompAttr
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,522 DPU in init phase
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,584 >> SetDetected
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:39,584 >> SetDetected
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,584 disconnect
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,600 getJobState 3 from 5b88e
DPU[3:CZZAAR1124] 27/05 10:38:39,600 DPU ends
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:39,631 disconnect
DPU[2:CZZAAS1003] 27/05 10:38:39,631 DPU ends
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,756 >> GetManagerData
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,850 >> SetCompInfo
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,881 >> GetContainerList
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,897 getJobState 3 from 5b8a9
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,897 getJobState 3 from 5b8a9
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:39,991 >> SetCompAttr
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:40,100 >> SetDetected
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:40,116 disconnect
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:40,116 getJobState 3 from 5b8a9
DPU[4:CZZAAR1125] 27/05 10:38:40,116 DPU ends
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:40,741  **AND** 0 Agents triggered
JCE[1] 27/05 10:38:42,756 JCE ends
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:47,475  **AND** 0 Agents triggered
DM[1] 27/05 10:38:54,241  **AND** 0 Agents triggered
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved ultimately by installing the latest MS SQL 2000 service packs prior installing the Service Pack for the OS.